# How to change the parent of a mesh in Blender 2.70a?

Tags: outliner

This is probably a bit of a weird question, but I'm doing a project that requires me to work in Houdini, and then import the mesh to blender for it to be imported to the sims 4 as custom content. The problem is that I can't figure out how to parent the imported geometry to the existing geometry node (which I removed all faces/vertices in).

Is there a way to do this? If not, is it possible to copy and paste the imported geometry into the existing (now empty) group?

[image]

The end goal is to have 'TestCube' replace 's4studio_mesh_1', but I can't remove the testcube parent object.

Comment: Are you sure the Blender version in the title is correct? 2.70a was released in April 2014! The current version is 3.4.1.

Comment: Unfortunately it is version 2.70a. The program to import custom content exclusively (as far as I know) uses 2.70a as I believe that's the version that was out when the program is released, and it hasn't updated to the newest blender version

Comment: Hmm. Can't help in that case. The oldest version I have here is 2.83.

Comment: No worries, turns out there's a beta version that uses 3.3, so I'll be switching to that which will hopefully solve my issue.